# how can i update price in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuex

i'm trying to change the shipping price when the component has been mounted

this is my template

```
 <div>
  <input
   type="radio"
  name="order"
   checked="checked"                   
    @change="onChooseShipping('normal')"
 /> Normal
 </div>
```

this is how i call the function in my mounted

```
  async mounted() {
      try {
     //   console.log(shipment)
        let response = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/shipment", {
          shipment: normal
        });
        console.log(response)
        this.$store.commit("setShipping", {
          price: response.shipment.price,
          estimatedDelivery: response.shipment.estimated
        });
        this.price = response.shipment.price;
        this.estimatedDelivery = response.shipment.estimated;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
```

this is my json object when i click on the shipping price

```
{
    "success": true,
    "shipment": {
        "estimated": "Tuesday August 30th",
        "price": 13.98
    }
}
```

This is my error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'price')
    at VueComponent.mounted
```

Comment: Are you seeing a `data` prop in response?  See if you can see `response.data.shipment.price`

Comment: @danh  thank you it now working, I changed my commit function to  response.data.shipment.price, you can just answer the question so I'll upvote it

Answer (score 1):

I just added data in my commit function

```
async mounted() {
      try {
     //   console.log(shipment)
        let response = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/shipment", {
          shipment: normal
        });
        console.log(response)
        this.$store.commit("setShipping", {
          price: response.data.shipment.price,
          estimatedDelivery: response.data.shipment.estimated
        });
        this.price = response.shipment.price;
        this.estimatedDelivery = response.shipment.estimated;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you got it!